# Binary search algorithm for 2D array Python

Tags: python, binary-search

I have been taught the 1D array way of doing binary search:

```
def exist(target, array):
  lower = -1 
  upper = len(array)
  while not (lower + 1 == upper):
    mid = (lower + upper)//2
    if target== array[mid]: 
      return True
    elif target< array[mid]: 
      upper = mid 
    else: 
      lower = mid 
  return False
```

However, now I am faced with this 2D array `list2` that takes in employee_id and employee_birthyear:

```py
[[2, 1986],
 [4, 1950],
 [6, 1994],
 [9, 2004],
 [12, 1988],
 [13, 1964],
 [16, 1987],
 [18, 1989],
 [19, 1951],
 [20, 1991]]
```

I want to write a function using the above pure binary search algorithm that takes in a year (as an integer) and `list2`, and returns a list of employee_id with matching employee_birthyear.

How do i do this?

Here's what i have thought of:

```
lst2 = [ j for i in list2 for j in i]

def get_IDs_with_birthyear(year, lst2):
    lower = -1 
  upper = len(lst2)
  while not (lower + 1 == upper): 
    mid = (lower + upper)//2
    if year = lst2[mid]:
      return mid 
  return []
```

**Updates**:
I tried sorting my `year` and doing the binary search, but when there are multiple `id` with the same year, I am unable to retrieve all the ids.

```
ids = [] 
def get_IDs_with_birthyear(year, employee_with_birthyear_list):
  data2 = sorted(employee_with_birthyear_list, key=lambda d: d[1])
  years = [d[1] for d in data2]
  id = [d[0] for d in data2]
  
  lower = -1 
  upper = len(years)
  while not (lower + 1 == upper): 
    mid = (lower + upper)//2
    if year == years[mid]:
      ids.append(id[mid])
      return ids
    elif year < years[mid]:
      upper = mid 
    else: 
      lower = mid
  return False
```

Result is supposed to get [101, 201, 1999632, 1999649], but instead i got only [1999632]

```
result = get_IDs_with_birthyear(1949, ewby)
```

What am i doing wrong in my function?

Comment: This a filtering problem, not a binary search problem. Binary search halves the search space on each iteration. Unless your data are sorted by year, binary search could potentially throw out matches... What you really want is to iterate through your 2D list and filter out those that do not match the birth year.

Comment: To clarify, binary search is typically used when searching for a single value of interest, not a subset. Binary search also requires the input data to be sorted.

Comment: You can do this if your list is sorted by year; in general, binary search relies on the data being sorted according to some total order, and there is no one 'natural' total order on 2D points.

Comment: Binary search is actually good for finding ranges and not just single values. Take a look at the answer I posted that addresses finding ranges.

Comment: Hi everyone! yes i understand the issues with using this method but this was what my assignment required me to do, i have used kcsquared and @Todd 's suggestions by sorting the year then doing the search but faced with another issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary search algorithm needs the data to be sorted on the key you are searching on.  In this case your 2D list is not sorted by year so you will need a different approach (or you'll need to resort the list on years instead of employee IDs).

One option would be to build a dictionary with the year as key:

```
years = dict()
for emp,birth in employee_birthyear:
    years.setdefault(birth,[]).append(emp)
```

Then you can get the list of employee IDs for any given birth year:

```
years[1950] # [4]
```

*Note that you get a list of employee IDs because you could have more than one employee born the same year*

Once the dictionary is build (an O(N) operation as opposed to O(NlogN) for a sort), all accesses by year will return in O(1).  This avoids the need to change the order of elements in the employee_birthyear list and has lower complexity than a binary search (which is O(logN))

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for binary searches, and maintaining a sorted list.

To search on dates, the data will need to be sorted on date, and a secondary list of keys (dates) constructed. `bisect_left()` can then be used to find the start of records >= the start date of choice.

```py
>>> from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
>>>
>>> data  = [[2, 1986],[4, 1950],[6, 1994],[9, 2004],[12, 1988],
...          [13, 1964],[16, 1987],[18, 1989],[19, 1951],[20, 1991]]
>>>
>>> # Sort data by date, then construct array of just dates.
>>> data2 = sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[1])
>>> dates = [d[1] for d in data2]
>>>
>>> # Use bisect_left() to locate the start of records >= 1988.
>>> idx = bisect_left(dates, 1988)
>>> data2[idx]     # Use that index with data2 to get first record.
[12, 1988]
>>>
>>> # Iteratively get records between 1988 and 1991.
>>> idx = bisect_left([d[1] for d in data2], 1988)
>>> recs = []
>>> while idx < len(data2) and data2[idx][1] <= 1991:
...     recs.append(data2[idx])
...     idx += 1
...     
>>> recs
[[12, 1988], [18, 1989], [20, 1991]]
>>> 
>>>
```

This is a flexible solution, since the date you want to find may not actually be within any records and a dictionary lookup will fail. By getting the first record >= a date, you can then iterate forward to find the subsequent records by ascending date. You could also specify an end date and find its position in the array using `bisect_right()` so you'll have an inclusive range of records of interest.

```py
>>> # A function that returns records that fall between 
>>> # specific dates, inclusive.
>>> def get_range(sorted_data, year_begin, year_end):
...     dates     = [d[1] for d in sorted_data]
...     idx_start = bisect_left(dates, year_begin)
...     idx_end   = bisect_right(dates, year_end)
...     return sorted_data[idx_start:idx_end]
...     
>>> get_range(data2, 1988, 1994)
[[12, 1988], [18, 1989], [20, 1991], [6, 1994]]
>>>
>>> # Add some more records for 1988 & sort.
>>> data2.extend([[1, 1988], [3, 1988]])
>>> data2.sort(); data2.sort(key=lambda r: r[1])
>>> 
>>> # Retrieve all records with 1988.
>>> get_range(data2, 1988, 1988)
[[1, 1988], [3, 1988], [12, 1988]]
```

If the data set is relatively small and you just want to get records that have a specific date, you don't need to sort or use any of the above approaches. You can just filter the data set.

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda d: d[1] == 1988, data2))
[[1, 1988], [3, 1988], [12, 1988]]
```

Comment: I tried your advice but used the original binary search algorithm instead of ```bisect_left```, however was unable to produce all ids that have the same year, instead only produced one id

Comment: @user101112, take a look at the function I just added above.